# Specify block background image without specifying the height and width

Tags: html, css

I have next structure in my site header:

html

```
<header>
 <div class='logo'></div>
 <div class='header'></div>
</header>
```

css

```
header .logo {
 background-image: url('../images/logo.png');
 width: 150px;
 height: 165px;
}

header .header {
 background-image: url('../images/header.png');
 width: 960px;
 height: 57px;
}
```

How to set up div's background-images without specifying the height and width?

Comment: Add some content to div's ;)

Comment: if you don't have any content in the divs, then they'll be displayed as zero-size, meaning you won't see ANY background because you can't display something in an area that's `0` in size. hence having to specific the height/width, so the browser knows that they SHOULD have some size to them.

Comment: but I don't need any content. I just want image here that's all

Comment: You either need to have content or specify dimensions, or use absolute positioning and pin edges to the parent container.

Comment: Sharikov is correct.  Even if there is nothing there but a backdrop, you have to give it a size, or it will display as 0x0.

Comment: What you are asking is not possible. A div is an empty container till you put text, images in it or you set the dimensions with CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like what you want is for the background images to fit these containers without explicitly setting a height and width. I would recommend using `background-size: cover`, `background-position: center` and `background-repeat: no-repeat` to accomplish this. Alternatively, if you don't want to cover the entire div (maybe in the case of the logo) you could set the width as a percentage and the height as auto (or vice versa).

Answer (score 0):

*If you don't want content in the divs and don't like setting the height and width in css, but do wish to set the image in rthe CSS and not directly in the html*  - **you could have a play with :**

```
<header>
 <div class='logo'></div>
 <div class='header'></div>
</header>
```

**CSS / content:""**

```
header .logo:after {
 content: url('../images/logo.png');
}

header .header:after {
 content: url('../images/header.png');
}
```

http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-gencontent

---

Comment: * that's a lot of don't likes and do likes : )

Answer (score -1):

If you want the `div` to have a size without setting it explicitly, you need to add content to it, such as some text.

If you don't want the `div` to have any content, then why use a `div` tag? Perhaps an `img` tag would be better?

Comment: You don't always need content inside a div to give it a size. You can simply set the height using css!

Comment: Yes, but I was working under the assumption that the original poster doesn't want to do that, since he specified that in his question. Edited my response.